# App Engine Could not guess mimetype for PHP files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mime-types, app.yaml

Google App Engine, PHP, Mimetype, app.yaml, static_dir, script, static_files

When I deploy my website, the PHP files are causing the error msg:

> Could not guess mimetype for

This is the `appl.yaml` configuration file:

```
application: applicationname
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /Client_Pages
  static_dir: Client_Pages
```

The files that cause the error, are not loading in the deployed website.  The same files work perfectly running from `Google App Engine Launcher` on my computer.

The `index.php` file in the root directory does not cause and error, and runs in the deployed website.

It seems that my deployed website will load either `PHP` files ***OR*** static `html` files but not both?  I have both `PHP` and `HTML` files in the same `Client_Pages` folder.  I'm wondering if that is causing a problem, but I can't find any documentation that states that I can't have them in the same folder.

I tried referring to the `PHP` files explicitly in the `app.yaml` file, and that causes the `PHP` files to run, but the `HTML` files won't load.

```
application: yardsalesuperhighway
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /Client_Pages/Offered_Menu.php
  script: Client_Pages/Offered_Menu.php

- url: /Client_Pages/InputForm.php
  script: Client_Pages/InputForm.php

- url: /Client_Pages/WantedPage.php
  script: Client_Pages/WantedPage.php

- url: /Client_Pages
  static_dir: Client_Pages
```

Answer (score 2):

Your application cant access files  stored in a static_dir without a specific directive.

From the docs -

> application_readable
>
> Optional. By default, files declared in static file handlers are
>   uploaded as static data and are only served to end users, they cannot
>   be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the files are
>   also uploaded as code data so your application can read them.

I am not sure a handler in app.yaml can overlap with a static directory.  It's not something I have tested and I would not be surprised if it's impossible.  Application code is uploaded into a different service in the appengine infrastructure.

Comment: In the past I've used: `- url: /Client_Pages
  static_dir: Client_Pages` without any other specification, and `App Engine` served all the files out of that directory.  But that was when I was just using all `html` files.

Comment: Thats correct it would work.  However now you are trying to get it to execute php code from the same static directory, and I don't believe it is possible.  AT the most you can, with that directive allow php code to read those files in the static directory, but I don't believe your primary handler can be located there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the post is still open. I seem to have encountered a similar problem and this worked for me. What I did was add `application_readable: true` and `mime_type: text/html` under my directory where I keep my php files. So maybe your `app.yaml` should look like:

```
application: yardsalesuperhighway
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /Client_Pages/Offered_Menu.php
  script: Client_Pages/Offered_Menu.php

- url: /Client_Pages/InputForm.php
  script: Client_Pages/InputForm.php

- url: /Client_Pages/WantedPage.php
  script: Client_Pages/WantedPage.php

- url: /Client_Pages
  application_readable: true # allow for php scripts in the dir to be executable by the application (as specified in the documentation provided by Tim)
  mime_type: text/html # assuming the php scripts will be echoing something, have what the echo as html (I got the mime types from http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)
  static_dir: Client_Pages
```

I got my code to work with this and it even worked with and even HTML files in the same directory as the php scripts were able to load.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using static_dir, consider using static_files to only upload the files you want to be static:

```
handlers:

- url: /Client_Pages/(.*\.php)
  script: Client_Pages/\1

- url: /Client_Pages/(.*\.html)
  static_files: Client_Pages/\1
  upload: Client_Pages/.*\.html

- url: /
  script: index.php
```